# how to retrieve date from db without seconds

Tags: mysql, sql

```
+---------+---------------------+
| user_id | registration_date   |
+---------+---------------------+
|    6988 | 2017-07-24 12:10:29 |
|    6985 | 2017-07-23 12:10:00 |
|    6980 | 2017-07-22 11:10:40 |
|    6979 | 2017-07-21 02:30:00 |
|    6978 | 2017-07-20 08:10:15 |
|    6977 | 2017-07-19 12:10:29 |
|    6976 | 2017-07-18 12:10:00 |
|    6975 | 2017-07-17 05:10:02 |
|    6974 | 2017-07-16 06:10:11 |
|    6951 | 2017-07-15 09:10:50 |
+---------+---------------------+


select registration_date from users WHERE registration_date BETWEEN '2017-07-24 12:10' - INTERVAL 10 DAY AND '2017-07-24 12:10';
```

I am having this data in my sql table and i am trying to get the data between 2017-07-24 12:10 and INTERVAL 10 DAY AND '2017-07-24 12:10'(excluding seconds).

Now i want to get this |    6988 | 2017-07-24 12:10:29 |   ...Means i want to ignore the seconds value from the data that is stored in the db and then get the data.so that the desired data with user_id 6988 will come.

```
select registration_date from users WHERE registration_date BETWEEN '2017-07-24 12:10' - INTERVAL 10 DAY AND '2017-07-24 12:10';
```

I am trying this...But not working .

Comment: mysql or (MS)SQL-Server? remove the tags which are wrong

Comment: @jens mysql server...

Comment: Dare we ask Why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the min and max value for seconds. In start add the `00` and for the range end `59` as seconds

```
select registration_date from users 
  WHERE registration_date BETWEEN '2017-07-24 12:10:00' - INTERVAL 10 DAY 
    AND '2017-07-24 12:10:59';
```

Comment: I am getting a variable with this 2017-07-24 12:10 value. I cant add the min and max value for seconds.

Comment: @Jayesh Why not? `use concat(your variable, ':00')` and `concat(your variable, ':59)`

Comment: @Jayesh i would do this in Java not in HQL

Answer (score 0):

For MySQL, you can use `DATE` and `STR_TO_DATE` functions to extract/compare dates, e.g.:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(registration_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') 
FROM users 
WHERE registration_date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('2017-07-24 12:10', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') - INTERVAL 10 DAY) 
      AND STR_TO_DATE('2017-07-24 12:10', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i');
```

[Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) the documentation.

Comment: This removes the time completely, he just wants to remove the seconds.

Comment: @Jayesh can you add some more info? i.e. error text etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATE_FORMAT` to get the parts of the date that you want, and compare this.

Since you want a range of dates, you need to test that separately from the time.

```
WHERE DATE(registration_date) BETWEEN '2017-07-14' AND '2017-07-24'
AND DATE_FORMAT(registration_date, '%H:%i') = '12:10'
```